# AVFoundation camera zooming and rotating issue

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, avfoundation

I use following method for rotating my camera which works perfectly 
this method is for not rotating but setting camera view like if we do ipad up down then camera will move same up down

```
-(void)rotateLayer{
    CALayer * stuckview = [[self captureManager] previewLayer];
    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation =[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];

    switch (orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            stuckview.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI+ M_PI_2); // 270 degress

            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            stuckview.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); // 90 degrees
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
           stuckview.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); // 180 degrees
            break;
        default:
            stuckview.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
            [stuckview setBounds:layerRect];
            break;
    }
    [stuckview setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
}
```

and I have slider for zooming the camera and this is how I zoom

```
-(void)sliderAction:(UISlider*)sender{



    howMuchToZoom = sender.value;
    CGAffineTransform affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(sender.value, sender.value);
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(affineTransform, sender.value, sender.value);
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(affineTransform, 0);
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:.025];
    //previewLayer is object of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    [[[self captureManager]previewLayer] setAffineTransform:affineTransform];

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

now the issue is when i zoom then zoom happen but if i move ipad up down then camera is moving left right so how could i solve this issue

Comment: Can you please explain your issue in more understandable format? Thanks!

Comment: issue is when camera is on in application and i move ipad up down then it camera layer get moved left right same like remember in games there is option of mouse vertical and horizontal you move your mouse up down but your aim is getting moved left right you know what i am mean if you have played many games by the way thank you for taking your time :)